# Wordpress: get_the_post_thumbnail_url by id defined in value of custom field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i am trying to accomplish to get_the_post_thumbnail_url by a post-id defined in a custom field. Something like this:

```
<?php $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( 'the_field('portfolio_similar_project_1')', 'thumbnail' ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
```

This works:

```
<?php $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( 53, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you be more explicit about your question? You're showing something that works and asking for ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the_field() will try to echo the result. You need to use get_field() instead. This will just return the value, and will allow you to pass it into get_the_post_thumbnail_url().

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_field('portfolio_similar_project_1'), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
```